# Cannot open php file using local characters inside url

Tags: php, url

**šuma.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html  lang="hr">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ŠUMA</title>
</head>

<body>
ć č đ š ž
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works well, but if I add some `php` code to this file and save it as `šuma.php` (instead of `šuma.html`) I cannot open it in browser via localhost (`xampp`). What I get is:

`Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

I suppose the same is on remote server.

Any help.

Comment: please show us your relevant php code.

Comment: Your browser will treat this as `%C5%A1uma.php`, Try with this

Comment: @lolka_bolka, concrete `php` code is not relevant here. Problem occurs if any piece of `php` code is added, for example `$a=5`. So, problem is about file extension.

Comment: Just a hunch, but this seems like a problem with web server configuration (namely, php FPM or mod_php, I'm not sure about your web server configuraion) rather than PHP. Anyawy, as a rule of thumb, you should use only basic english alphabet in PHP file names. You never know, how the web server will be configured...

Comment: @Rishi, I tried, but Chrome automatically changes it to `šuma.php` and the same warning appears.

Comment: @bonaca I see, sorry, I missunderstood your question. This will be server configuration as Tomasz sad.